# Nodejs process restarts itself after kill

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, process, forever

I know that forever can be used to restart a nodejs process when it crashes or is killed.

I have to administrate a server that is using a nodejs process to serve a website. Every time I kill the process it is restarted with a new PID. I know forever is not restarting the process because it doesn't appear on the `forever list` and I don't see the monitor porcess.

How can I know which process or service is restarting my nodejs process and how can I prevent it from happening. This is the result of `ps xu` running sudo:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.3  29272  3784 ?        Ss   Mar19   1:26 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19   0:11 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19   3:12 [rcu_sched]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19   2:24 [rcuos/0]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19   0:00 [rcuob/0]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19   0:00 [migration/0]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19   0:44 [watchdog/0]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [khelper]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [netns]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19   0:04 [khungtaskd]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [writeback]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Mar19   0:00 [ksmd]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Mar19   0:34 [khugepaged]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [crypto]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [bioset]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [kblockd]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [ata_sff]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19   0:00 [khubd]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [md]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [devfreq_wq]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19   0:05 [kswapd0]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root        33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
root        45  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [kthrotld]
root        46  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [acpi_thermal_pm]
root        47  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19   0:00 [vballoon]
root        48  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root        49  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [scsi_tmf_0]
root        50  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root        51  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [scsi_tmf_1]
root        53  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
root        73  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [deferwq]
root        74  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [charger_manager]
root       120  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root       127  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19   4:33 [jbd2/vda1-8]
root       128  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root       249  0.0  0.2  23700  2632 ?        Ss   Mar19   0:00 /sbin/cgmanager --sigstop -m name=systemd
root       308  0.0  0.1  24088  1848 ?        S    Mar19   0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
root       316  0.0  0.2  34868  2604 ?        Ss   Mar19   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd --daemon
root       360  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [ttm_swap]
root       428  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar19   0:00 [kvm-irqfd-clean]
root       643  0.0  0.1  15684  1460 ?        S    Mar19   0:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
root       808  0.0  0.1  15304  1192 ?        S    Mar19   0:00 upstart-file-bridge --daemon
root       954  0.0  0.1  15844  1948 tty4     Ss+  Mar19   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
root       959  0.0  0.1  15844  2016 tty5     Ss+  Mar19   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
root       966  0.0  0.1  15844  1812 tty2     Ss+  Mar19   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
root       968  0.0  0.1  15844  1848 tty3     Ss+  Mar19   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
root       971  0.0  0.1  15844  1804 tty6     Ss+  Mar19   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
root       973  0.0  0.2  26028  2304 ?        Ss   Mar19   0:19 cron
root       975  0.0  0.1   4368  1616 ?        Ss   Mar19   0:00 acpid -c /etc/acpi/events -s /var/run/acpid.socket
root      1009  0.0  0.4  59576  4376 ?        Ss   Mar19   4:07 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root      1084  0.0  0.0  12732   132 ?        Ss   Mar19   0:00 /usr/sbin/uuidd
root      1258  0.0  0.1  15844  1868 tty1     Ss+  Mar19   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
root      1292  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19   0:00 [kauditd]
root      1294  0.0  0.2  36760  2940 ?        S    Mar19   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
root      1407  0.0  1.4  61752 14488 ?        S    Mar19  20:35 /root/.virtualenvs/deployweb/bin/python3 /root/.virtualenvs/deployweb/bin/gunico
root      1410  0.0  2.8 156400 29260 ?        S    Mar19   2:06 /root/.virtualenvs/deployweb/bin/python3 /root/.virtualenvs/deployweb/bin/gunico
root      1411  0.0  2.9 156876 29560 ?        S    Mar19   2:09 /root/.virtualenvs/deployweb/bin/python3 /root/.virtualenvs/deployweb/bin/gunico
root      1412  0.0  2.9 156788 29548 ?        S    Mar19   2:22 /root/.virtualenvs/deployweb/bin/python3 /root/.virtualenvs/deployweb/bin/gunico
root      2088  0.0  0.4  87192  4640 ?        Ss   Apr22   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
root      3048  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar24   0:00 [kworker/0:1H]
root     10512  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:38   0:00 [kworker/0:2]
root     11330  0.0  0.4  87192  4548 ?        S    06:48   0:00 nginx: worker process
root     11331  0.0  0.4  87192  4548 ?        S    06:48   0:00 nginx: worker process
root     11332  0.0  0.3  87192  3860 ?        S    06:48   0:00 nginx: worker process
root     11333  0.0  0.3  87192  3860 ?        S    06:48   0:00 nginx: worker process
root     11650  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:13   0:00 [kworker/0:0]
root     11656  0.0  0.6  99532  6544 ?        Ss   07:13   0:00 sshd: root@pts/0    
root     11731  0.0  0.5  23196  5868 pts/0    Ss   07:13   0:00 -bash
root     11782  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:14   0:00 [kworker/u2:1]
root     11819  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:20   0:00 [kworker/u2:0]
root     11952  0.3  8.2 1003880 84196 ?       Ssl  07:25   0:02 node /home/admin/deployweb/server/app.js
root     12038  1.0  0.6  98320  6272 ?        Ss   07:37   0:00 sshd: root [priv]   
root     12041  0.0  0.2  18440  2252 pts/0    R+   07:37   0:00 ps xu
root     17745  0.0  1.4 267476 14284 ?        Ss   Apr23   0:30 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)                    
root     22796  0.0  0.2  27368  2496 ?        Ss   Apr13   0:00 SCREEN
root     22797  0.0  0.2  21228  2624 pts/2    Ss+  Apr13   0:00 /bin/bash
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The process i want to kill is 11952

Answer (score 0):

How are you starting it?

Due to the fact that the user is root, I suppose it is started as a service.
If so it can be the system itself to restart the service automatically.

For example in Upstart it is done by the respawn directive.
http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn

Is this the case?